# IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition when having a double call in same method

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

```
public class Holder() {

    Contact contact1;
    Contact contact2;
}

public class ContactServiceImpl() {

    public Contact create(Contact contact) {
        // do create
    }
}

public class HolderServiceImpl() {
    ContactService contactService = new ContactServiceImpl();

    public Holder createHolder(Holder holder) {
        contactService.create(holder.getContact1());
        contactService.create(holder.getContact2());

        return holder;
    }
}

pulbic class HolderServiceTest() {
    ContactServiceImpl contactService = new ContactServiceImpl();
    HolderServiceImpl holderService = new HolderServiceImpl();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        contactService = EasyMock.createMock(ContactServiceImpl.class);     
        holderService.setContactServiceImpl(contactService);
        EasyMock.expect(contactService.create(EasyMock.isA(Contact.class))).andReturn(new Contact()).anyTimes();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        Holder holder = new Holder();

        holderService.create(holder)
    }
}
```

When not setting the replay, I have an error on the second call of contactService.create which is IllegalStateException.

However when adding (After the expect call) :

```
EasyMock.replay(contactService);
```

I get this error:

```
Unexpected method call ContactServiceImpl.create(Contact@4ebd441a[
```

I tried using PowerMock but I get the same issue. Is it even possible to have both calls like that? Anytimes() seems to exist for that use but it's not working much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what was wrong is that my method testCreate was missing the setters on contact1 and contact2 which caused the error.

I had the option of either:

1. Setting both objects
2. Using ***EasyMock.isNull(Contact.class)*** instead of ***EasyMock.isA(Contact.class)***.

However since it was possible for in real cases to have either one of them as null, the best solution was to use ***EasyMock.anyObject(Contact.class)*** which accepts both initiated objects or nulls.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    contactService = EasyMock.createMock(ContactServiceImpl.class);     
    holderService.setContactServiceImpl(contactService);
    EasyMock.expect(contactService.create(EasyMock.anyObject(Contact.class))).andReturn(new Contact()).anyTimes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never did put the mock in replay state. Just add `EasyMock.replay(contactService);` at the end of your `setUp` method.

Comment: isn't that what I did? After the expect call = end of the setUp method

Comment: Now yes. But I did exactly what you did. And I had to fix a bunch of syntax errors to make it work. So I think your actual code is different from the code above. For instance, you seem to call a method typed `ContactServiceImpl.create(Contact[] contacts)` or `ContactServiceImpl.create(Contact... contacts)`

Comment: I dont understand how you see an array in the create method. (I've changed my test method since it was wrong)

Comment: Because of Contact@4ebd441a[. But now that I'm thinking a bit more about it, It think it's Contact.toString that is printing that (but the end of the message is truncated)